# Ios 9 update error

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update, error

My iPad is stuck at connect to iTunes when uploading to IOS 9. It says restore and then it gets to the point where it say verifying with Apple then gives unknown error 9. I have tried all the steps Apple suggest when this error happens including DFU mode and no luck please help.

Comment: What iPad version is it? (i.e. 2,3,4,Air, Air 2?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Apple Says about your Error Message:

"Check your security software
Errors: 2, 4, 6, 9, 1611, 9006.
Sometimes security software can stop your device from communicating with either the Apple update server or with your device.
Check your security software and settings to make sure that they aren't blocking a connection to the Apple servers.
If you still see the error message, check for USB connection issues."

I say:

1. Connect your iPhone or iOS device to your computer
2. Select the device in iTunes
3. On a Mac, hold down the “Option” key and then click on “Update”
4. On a Windows PC, hold down “SHIFT” key and then click on “Update”
5. Select the IPSW file you downloaded and click “Choose”
6. Let the iOS device update as usual

**iOS 9.0.2 IPSW Files (Software Update)**

**These are the most recent updates as of October 5th 2015**

[iPad Air 2 (Wifi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37601-20150930-7EC46192-64A0-11E5-B7FB-40E151D92A8C/iPad5,3_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad Air 2 (Wifi + Cellular)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37506-20150930-7EC4482E-64A0-11E5-8881-42E151D92A8C/iPad5,4_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad Air 1 (Wifi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37403-20150930-7EC3A694-64A0-11E5-9664-3AE151D92A8C/iPad4,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad Air 1 (Wifi + Cellular)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37382-20150930-7EC52E9C-64A0-11E5-AA52-3CE151D92A8C/iPad4,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad Air 1 (China)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37154-20150930-7EC3B6A2-64A0-11E5-9D00-3EE151D92A8C/iPad4,3_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad (4th generation CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37438-20150930-A6C61EA0-64A1-11E5-BB8C-65E451D92A8C/iPad3,6_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad (4th generation GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37147-20150930-A6532ABC-64A1-11E5-A29F-54E451D92A8C/iPad3,5_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad (4th generation WiFi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37598-20150930-A5B275C2-64A1-11E5-8B96-43E451D92A8C/iPad3,4_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37451-20150930-B343D6A4-64A1-11E5-AFEF-BBE451D92A8C/iPad2,7_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37646-20150930-B1FA0AF2-64A1-11E5-8F98-ABE451D92A8C/iPad2,6_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini (WiFi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37336-20150930-AD27F872-64A1-11E5-B8AC-93E451D92A8C/iPad2,5_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 2 (Cellular)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37382-20150930-7EC52E9C-64A0-11E5-AA52-3CE151D92A8C/iPad4,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 2 (WiFi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37302-20150930-7EC43B18-64A0-11E5-9C55-44E151D92A8C/iPad4,4_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 2 (China)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37543-20150930-7EC834E8-64A0-11E5-8C60-4CE151D92A8C/iPad4,6_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 3 (China)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37413-20150930-7EC5EDFA-64A0-11E5-84C2-4EE151D92A8C/iPad4,9_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 3 (WiFi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37126-20150930-7EC6F556-64A0-11E5-8550-46E151D92A8C/iPad4,7_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 3 (Cellular)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37530-20150930-7EC6171C-64A0-11E5-B818-4AE151D92A8C/iPad4,8_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 4 (WiFi)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37232-20150930-7EC87BBA-64A0-11E5-B6E5-50E151D92A8C/iPad5,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad mini 4 (Cellular)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37111-20150930-7EC85AFE-64A0-11E5-841D-52E151D92A8C/iPad5,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad 3 Wi-Fi (3rd generation)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37435-20150930-7EC2B108-64A0-11E5-8867-34E151D92A8C/iPad3,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad 3 Wi-Fi + Cellular (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37706-20150930-7EC429B6-64A0-11E5-95B9-38E151D92A8C/iPad3,3_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad 3 Wi-Fi + Cellular (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37366-20150930-7EC3CA20-64A0-11E5-8E21-36E151D92A8C/iPad3,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad 2 Wi-Fi (Rev A)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37359-20150930-7EC8714C-64A0-11E5-B397-56E151D92A8C/iPad2,4_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad 2 Wi-Fi](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37493-20150930-7EC95B66-64A0-11E5-9A5D-54E151D92A8C/iPad2,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37157-20150930-7ECBD7B0-64A0-11E5-9DC8-58E151D92A8C/iPad2,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37222-20150930-7ECD2660-64A0-11E5-B504-5AE151D92A8C/iPad2,3_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 5 (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37607-20150930-7ECEFDD2-64A0-11E5-969E-5FE151D92A8C/iPhone5,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 5 (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37195-20150930-7ECB44D0-64A0-11E5-A24C-5EE151D92A8C/iPhone5,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 5c (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37486-20150930-7ECEB732-64A0-11E5-ADC0-62E151D92A8C/iPhone5,4_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 5c (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37464-20150930-7ECE0B70-64A0-11E5-8471-61E151D92A8C/iPhone5,3_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 5s (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37599-20150930-55AA3B00-64A1-11E5-9CF0-C7E251D92A8C/iPhone6,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 5s (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37150-20150930-46C63616-64A1-11E5-AAFA-A3E251D92A8C/iPhone6,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 6](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37613-20150930-6145D2C6-64A1-11E5-B70C-14E351D92A8C/iPhone7,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 6 Plus](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37106-20150930-5C2A7F08-64A1-11E5-A0DB-E8E251D92A8C/iPhone7,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 6s](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-36894-20150930-6FC5C5D6-64A1-11E5-8ECB-63E351D92A8C/iPhone8,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 6s Plus](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-36893-20150930-61E92CB4-64A1-11E5-A76F-24E351D92A8C/iPhone8,2_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 4s](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37244-20150930-8AA55C68-64A1-11E5-9BD8-C3E351D92A8C/iPhone4,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPod touch (5th-generation)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37238-20150930-714F8DC4-64A1-11E5-AE09-74E351D92A8C/iPod5,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)

[iPod touch (6th-generation)](http://appldnld.apple.com/ios9.0.2/031-37266-20150930-7ECBB41A-64A0-11E5-AB00-5CE151D92A8C/iPod7,1_9.0.2_13A452_Restore.ipsw)